# cannot create custom folders in docker logstash image based container

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, logstash

i'm using logstash image and i have some ruby scripts that are located in the same directory as my dockerfile.

my goal is to create a script folder, and copy my scripts to it.

my problem is that when i access to the container instance, the folder is not created and no ruby file exist.

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${ELK_VERSION}
USER root
WORKDIR /usr/share/logstash
RUN mkdir scripts
COPY ./scripts/*.rb scripts
```

thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

this is the files structure

[image]

Comment: Can you share your file structure also?

Comment: @MustafaGüler the structure of the project or the structure inside the docker container?

Comment: Structure of the project

Comment: @MustafaGüler i've added the project structure

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you check with; 1 .`docker build -t newtag . ` 2. `docker run newtag` 3. `docker exec -it container_id ls scripts `